# Open multiple folders with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have on my computer an partition named H:
On that partition i have diffent folders with each a folder called "bin"
Example:

```
H:MyFolder\Bin
H:AnotherFolder\Bin
```

I know that I can delete bin with the follow command:

```
 set folder="H:\Bin"
 cd /d %folder%
 for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

Is it possible to empty all the bin folders from all folders in partition H: with a command?

Comment: A hint only: start with `dir /B /S /AD "H:\bin"` from command line. Then you could properly improve your `for /f` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove the content of all the `bin` folders under `H:\` while keeping the folders.

```dos
for /r "H:\" /d %%a in (bin) do @if exist "%%~fa\" ( pushd "%%~fa" && ( echo "%%~fa" & echo rmdir . /s /q & popd ))
```

There is an `echo` command that precedes the `rmdir`. This is included for testing and must be removed to perform the content removal.